# Selenium: How to only get displayed part of text when some of the string is hidden with CSS overflow hidden tag

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver

I have a web page that has some text in a  that has max height/width set as well as overflow-x & overflow-y hidden set so that not all the text is displayed in the browser.
I want to be able to get ONLY the text that is displayed in the browser (visible to the user) not all the text that is contained in the

Have tried using the standard driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span#value1').text
But I get the full value of the span, not just the value on the screen

Given the following HTML

```
<span style="display: inline-block;/* max-width: 80%; */height: 1.5em;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;/* white-space: nowrap; *//* border: 3px; */border-style:solid;/* border-color:#FF0000; */padding: 1em;max-width: 5;max-height: 10;>
A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F A B C D E F 11111111111 11111111111
</span>
```

With the following Python Selenium Selector

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span").text
```

I want to only get the displayed text i.e AB

Comment: There is no way in selenium to do that, Selenium will fetch all the text within an element. But if you know precisely that only first two characters of the string is going to be visible, get the complete string and get the sub-string of first two characters.

Comment: @nigeu store your text into string and trim your data it will help you out.

Comment: I could do that but the trouble is we wanted to check what the actual user was seeing in the Browser.   I guess we will have to validate that the whole text of the element is correct and maybe some of the CSS values to make sure that they are set correctly to only display X number of characters on the screen.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might measure displayed text by width, then performing comparison with original string.